# Would this questions be on topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-ness

I want to ask a question, but I'm wondering if it's on topic here. It's a question about if I should even bother writing up a paper, but the work is in Abstract Algebra, so maybe [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) would be a better fit? Or if anyone can refer me to duplicates that I might have missed.

> Let's assume I've built a probabilistic non-determinant model. I've
>   developed my own notation, described my own objects, and shown some
>   properties to be true about these objects.
>
> My work isn't based on any previous work, so I have no citations. It
>   isn't ground breaking, and I'm under no illusions that I'm the next
>   Euler. But I do think it might eventually be a useful tool for others,
>   if they see it and possibly draw similarities between my work and
>   other fields. I would certainly like to see it extended by others, and
>   see where it might lead.
>
> I'm wondering if it would be worthwhile to put work into actually
>   writing up my model and results into a paper to try to submit
>   somewhere? It would basically be a paper full of definitions, plus
>   proofs of a few properties resulting from those definitions.
>
> NOTE: I don't think this is a dupe, I'm not asking if an [independent
>   researcher can submit a paper](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/3010/93648), or where such a paper could be
>   submitted. Nor if such a paper or the work might help later in my
>   career. I just want to know if such a paper would even be read,
>   anywhere, by anyone. Should I bother taking the time to write it up,
>   or just keep working on it by myself.
>
> 2nd NOTE (before anyone asks): It's mathematical work. I've built up
>   notation and a probabilistic system of objects, defined their
>   relations, and shown certain classes of these objects are a Group, and
>   possibly a Ring, under certain constraints. I'd like to see if others
>   can extend my work further into Algebra, Topology, or Geometry.

Answer (score 5):

Academia.SE is not intended to answer if questions about **specific research subjects** are publishable. If that is your primary concern, you need to use one of the subject-specific groups.

As a rule of thumb, if you can generalize your concern so that a future visitor can have her question answered as well, it belongs here.

Comment: I think math SO doesn't like questions about publications either. I'm not sure where to take this question.

Comment: My primary concern is if I should work on writing a paper of foundational work, with no real results. Shouldn't that apply to all academia? So then my question becomes, how can I generalize this enough to be applicable to this stack?

Comment: Then focus on the question you just asked. That is definitely an on-topic question, and we can work to get it into something answerable.

Comment: That is the point of this meta question, how to get my question on topic? What should I adjust?

Comment: The question might be titled something like: “how do I introduce the needed background info for a new field in a publication if I don’t have any results?” But otherwise the basis of your question seems OK—just try to prune details that aren’t essential.

Comment: I've seen many questions where the answer is "it depends on the subject", so I included that as a note, not part of the question

Comment: You could mention “math” as a tag.

Comment: I'll try that with the title and content. Thanks.

Comment: It's not a new field though, just possibly new tools in an established field. Any recommendations on how to title that?

Comment: “New framework?”

Comment: I'll wait until tomorrow to see if I get any more answers to this meta question, and I'll rephrase and post on the main site then

Comment: As a comment on your intended question: it will be up to you to place your work in the context of the field. You will have to understand the field, and cite relevant works.